# How do I approach optimizing this multivariable function? What should I learn to be able to do that?

Tags: optimization

#### Function to maximize

$R(P) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^4 (-\frac{1}{2}p_i^2 + 1000p_i)$

#### Parameters

$P = (p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4)$

#### Constraints

- $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4 > 0$
- $\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 (-\frac{1}{2}p_i + 1000) \leq 2000$

Comment: Convex optimization.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thanks for the hint! A quick google-search suggests that it should probably be done programmatically, right?

Comment: Because the $p_i$ are interchangeable, try setting them all equal so you have a one-dimensional optimization problem.  $p_i = 1000$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you for suggestion! That approach, as I understand, stands on the assumption that the prices for each period are going to be the same at the optimum. It makes intuitive sense to me but I haven't figured it out formally yet. Just documenting my thoughts...

Comment: I think you can argue as follows: the objective function is strictly concave, so there can only be one maximizer. Due to the symmetry in the problem, if $p_1, \ldots, p_4$ is a maximizer then any permutation of these four values must also be a maximizer. Since there can't be more than one maximizer, a maximizer must satisfy $p_1 = \cdots = p_4$.

Comment: An alternative technique from Convex Optimization is "Geometric Programing"  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_programming
I quite like it but it is basically the same.   In any case, a big clue is the symmetry under permutations of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first time I have answered a question, so please bear with me.

Maximizing $R(P)=\sum_1^4(−1/2p^2_i+1000p_i)$ is the same as minimizing its negative. Doubling it and adding 1000000 to each summand doesn't change the minimum and we get
$R(P)=\sum_1^4(p^2_i-2000p_i+1000000)$
$    =\sum_1^4(p_i-1000)^2$.
Setting each $p_1=1000$ satisfies the constraints and makes $R(P)=0$ and, since it is a sum of squares this must be the minimum.